# how to add new global gem in RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, global, rvm

I've a RVM stable installation and i want to add ruby-debug gem in my global set so that i don't have to install it in every gemset, that is, i want to be able to access it when i'm already inside any gemset i create

i added ruby-debug to my global.gems file but don't know what to do next

Answer (score 1):

switch into the global gemset for your installed version of Ruby

```
rvm use <RUBYVERSION>@global
```

Install ruby-debug as you want and you'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

When you put file into your global.gems they will be installed every time you install a new version of ruby or create a new gemset, you dont have to do anything. As far as the existing gems go I am not sure, but in case you dont find them you can install them manually.

Comment: i found this useful http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/gem-management-with-rvm-and-bundler